# Get on every 4th post in WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, php-5.3

I am currently trying to a create a feature on my category pages where on every 4th preview post, within the category an advert block is display.

essential it will work the following way:

1. post 1
2. post 2
3. post 3
4. post 4

**ADVERT BLOCK**

5. Post 5
6. Post 6

In my `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

I have the following:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php if (post_num ($i%4 == 0)  < (5 - $featured_count)) : echo "this works"; endif ?>
```

can someone guide me in the right direction

Comment: You can use offset in query

Comment: Please post an example

Comment: @Geme - OP didn't tag as jQuery, or show jQuery, not sure how that comment helps....

Comment: @cale_b query, not jQuery.   https://tommcfarlin.com/wp_query-offset/

Comment: // WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page'         => '4',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// ADVERT HERE 

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
 'posts_per_page'         => '4',
 'offset'                 => '4',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your more or less there, here's a quick example just showing some arbitrary text or the post title:

```
<?php
    $counter = 0;

    if (have_posts()) {
        while (have_posts()) {
            $counter++;
            the_post();

            if ($counter % 5 === 0) { 
                echo 'Advert Here!';
            } else {
                the_title();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I haven't tested this, but just to give you an idea.

Edit: I should note that since you're looking to insert the advert *after* the fourth post, `$counter % 4` won't do what you think, if you want to show four posts and then the advert, it would be placed in the 5th "position", hence `$counter % 5`.

Comment: Nice answer.  I'd encourage you to link to the [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator in your answer, and _potentially_ for readability (I know it's a code-style preference) wrap the mod operator in parens to make it somewhat easier to read: `if ( ( $counter % 5) == 0) {`.... (double-equals is all that is needed, triple equals isn't necessary, but again - more code style preference :)